# Help identifying story set in 2020 Italy about a boy and his Net-Plugged Games heterochromic magic character

Tags: story-identification

More than 5 years ago I read a story about this.

Set in 2020 Italy. One school boy's hobby is creating and playing Net-Plugged Games, which apparently have great graphical detail and can be created on a whim. He is creating his latest one to then play it and has the feeling something is lacking, when his little sister comes and changes one of the eyes of the character, giving the (female) character a blue and an amber eye. The boy, excited, starts the game.

Turns out the game creates the story about that girl being a bit magical, and absorbing energy from the sunset by covering her blue eye and looking at it with the amber one.

Things happen, and it turns out the setting of the game is in year 0 Christmas. The boy spots roman soldiers, Mary and Joseph, but decides to not let his character know.

In the real world, the boy finds a big moving nativity scene (some hobbyists do that) created by a Catholic priest in his town's church. They make friends. More things happen, and both the nativity scene and the game stop moving. The priest says something about an apocryphal gospel stating time stops, and that both 'toys' (the nativity scene and the Net-Plugged Game) stopped because they are well-made. The boy then finds out the magical character girl has been moving when the time is stopped, and that's her magic power.

At some point, the boy plays as a priest inside the game, remarking how novel the way of controlling him is: he has to chant prayers in latin into a microphone to make the priest "fight".

As you see, I remember quite a bit of details about the story, but I do not know its name nor its author. Please help?

Comment: Is "Net-Plugged Game" a term used uniquely in this book? I've never heard it before. Is it more similar to an MMORPG, or the newer virtual reality games?

Comment: I think it is, that is why I included it. If I recall correctly, in the book NPGs are more like a platform for making games that is really easy to use, and actually makes most of the game by itself. The game the book talks about is an RPG, and it's not virtual reality.

Comment: That phrase appears a lot in non-English language search results. Was the book in English?

Comment: I don't actually remember for sure, but it probably was not.

Comment: What language did you probably read this book in? Knowing that will really help us fine tune the search terms. Also, how do you write Net-Plugged Game in that language?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. The book was probably in Catalan, but it was probably a translation. "Net-Plugged Game" was written exactly like that, in English. Throughout the book it was written as the abbreviation "NPG".